# React-Native, space-between and wrap in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

I have implemented what I want with View but not with FlatList, I don't know how to pass some styles to the Flatlist.

### FlatList

[image: Flatlist output]

```
<FlatList
      columnWrapperStyle= {{flexWrap: "wrap"}}
      numColumns = {6}
      data={vols}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <Text style={styles.box}>{item}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </View>
```

### View

[image: View output]

```
      <View style={styles.itemslist}>
          { vols.map(vol => (
                  <Text style = {styles.box}>{ vol }</Text>
          )) }
      </View>
```

### Styles

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemslist: {
        marginTop: 50,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexWrap:"wrap",
        padding: 10,
    },
    box: {
      marginTop: 20,
      fontSize: 20,
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
      padding: 10,
    }
   });
```

Comment: Like this - https://snack.expo.dev/RC72-8x5Z ?

Comment: @Quintis change font size to 16 and you will see the same result with mine

Comment: numColumns was changed  -   https://snack.expo.dev/ZXuxWlLAq , now it is good

Comment: Im looking for a way to do this dynamically, if you change the length of the text you get the same problem.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/KjoeQJnlA - without numColumns

Comment: I want a result the same as the png with with the View